# How to encode an array with my encoding pattern?

Tags: php, arrays

how can I encode the contents of the array `$varcontent[$i]["images"]` as i did with `$varcontent[$i]["content"]` ?

```
$encoded = strtr(base64_encode(addslashes(gzcompress(serialize($nospaces),9))), '+/=', '-_,');

$varcontent[$i]["content"] = $encoded;
$varcontent[$i]["images"] = array_unique($filtered);
```

Thank you!

Comment: The code you posted is not valid. What are you trying to encode? with what exactly?

Comment: Use `$varcontent` or `$filtered` in place of `$VALUE`. You should elabarote on what you want to accomplish with that. The `strtr` and `addslashes` application doesn't look useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want array_map().  Try this:

```
function encodeElement($e)
{
    return strtr(base64_encode(addslashes(gzcompress(serialize($e),9))), '+/=', '-_,');
}
array_map("encodeElement", $array);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare encodeelement() (previously declared in. Maybe because I use it in a for loop

Comment: Maybe that function exists elsewhere and would probably be unrelated.  Try a different name.  You can always use a for loop, but array_map should work fine and can be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize an array directly, so you can simply do this:

`strtr(base64_encode(addslashes(gzcompress(serialize($varcontent),9))), '+/=', '-_,');`

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this bizarre string of functions, though, especially the odd choice to addslashes() immediately prior to a base64_encode()...

Comment: Hi Kromey, thanks. I have updated my question with the full code. Can you take a look ?